# Can Expresso Store or CartThrob be used without the shopping cart?

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, shopping-cart

I'm preparing to redesign my employer's website that features more than 18,000 items. We're not ready to open the site for online sales but may do so in the future. I'm considering integrating an e-commerce system from the beginning for the benefits --- search, sort, filter, product-focused display --- and to make it much simpler to open the site for sales later. Do either Expresso or CartThrob allow the shopping cart and Buy Now functions to be turned off while the rest of the features are in use?

Answer (score 1):

Cartthrob uses regular channels and entries for products, orders etc. so it's perfectly possible to set up your site without Cartthrob and add the shopping cart functionality later.

If you aren't building an ecommerce site yet then you don't need Cartthrob yet. When you want to start selling, install Cartthrob, configure it (tell it which channels are for products, set up orders channel etc., configure the payment gateway) then add your checkout templates and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem with using either of them without out actually using the shopping cart portion.

In Exp:resso Store you can simply add `disable_form="yes"` to the `{exp:store:product}` tag to prevent Store from creating a form that would allow the user to add the item to the cart. I would also recommend removing your submit button to make it less confusing for users.

CartThrob should have a similar functionality.

Either approach though the easiest way would be to just not include the template code to add an item to the cart.

Comment: That's great to hear, Justin. Thank you so much for the fast response!